# X-ray image of the Earth

Tags: astrophysics, x-rays

Since the Sun emits X-rays, what would happen if we had a hypothetically planet sized x-ray film and exposed it behind the earth?

I understand we wouldn't be able to see the insides of the earth, but what about around the edges, what would it look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the hospital, when an "X-ray" is taken, the film shows the parts that are opaque to x-rays (like bones) and does not show parts transparent to x-rays (like skin).

Now that this is established, https://www.nasa.gov/audience/forstudents/5-8/features/F_X_Rays.html tells us that the Earth's atmosphere is opaque to x-rays and practically absorbs all of it. So, on your hypothetical x-ray film, we would see a giant circle and a lot of black around it.

Comment: Apart from the aurorae.

Answer (score 8):

This experiment has sort-of been done. As far as I know, no X-ray satellite has captured an image of the Earth eclipsing the Sun, but HINODE observed an eclipse of the Sun by the Moon at X-ray wavelengths from Earth orbit.

[image: HINODE observation of an eclipse]

The presence of an atmosphere around the Earth would change things only slightly. The atmosphere is opaque to X-rays, so the occulting disk would be slightly larger than the radius of the Earth. Secondly, the Earth can have X-ray bright patches caused by aurorae.

Answer (score 5):

X-rays work by being absorbed in denser material, producing the shadow that is the traditional X-ray image. Medical X-rays are designed to top out looking at calcium-40 ($Z$=20). On an object the size of the Earth, the X-ray shadow isn't going to differ much from the optical shadow (except of course, for the atmosphere).

If materials are too dense, or high-$Z$, and in compact configuration, say spherical arrangements of plutonium-239, uranium-235/238, beryllium, aluminum, then you can use a proton beam to do tomography. Here, the protons can penetrate with different levels absorption, allowing a tomographic reconstruction of 3D material distributions. Here's some simulated image of The French Test Object from (https://permalink.lanl.gov/object/tr?what=info:lanl-repo/lareport/LA-UR-09-05353):

[image]

Now with the Earth, there really isn't a form of radiation that can both penetrate, and be differentially absorbed so that any useful information can be recovered. Neutrinos penetrate, but aren't absorbed enough to give any contrast.

For large objects, muon radiography is practical. It has been used on the Pyramids at Giza and is regularly used to detect dense objects in shipping containers. The source of muons is cosmic rays, and they have been used to look at the radiographic shadow of the moon (which isn't too dissimilar from the Earth in these regards) at IceCube:

[image]